# Metasploit Android encoder

Tags: python, ruby, security, encoder, metasploit

I am using metasploit framework I have installed it on termux apk I was making a payload for Android I got to know that encoding helps in making a perfect and undectactable payload but I am unable to find a encoder for Android in search so which encoder should I use for Android apk payload I am making meterpreter/reverse TCP connection

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

encoder/x86/shikata_ga_nai

excellent encoders